# If I plug in headphones with an integrated microphone, will the Wii U use it?

Tags: wii-u

If I plug in headphones with an integrated microphone, will the Wii U use that instead of the GamePad's microphone?

Comment: I'll double check on this one, but from previous experiences, it did seem like I was able to talk and listen using a standard mobile ear bud set. (While playing Smash 4 with friends)  Will need to test to make sure it was the headset mic and not the intergrated one that was running though.

Comment: @NBN-Alex There's a "microphone test" option in the system settings, can you try that?